# importing sql é turning into Ã©

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I forget what I need to do but when I import my sql database into a seperate site it is changing all of my special characters into Ã© well me é at least.

I am importing an sql file directly into phpmyadmin.

I believe the charset I chose was utf8 should I be choosing something else or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: if you open the sql file the character are correct? if they are you can know in what charset the file is and import using the same.

Comment: Interesting I will check

Comment: The characters were not correct when I open in editor. The file is being exported as utf8 should it be a different charset?

Comment: if the file is already with the wrong characters, you have to look what is the charset of the DB and export in it. Or with you use Notepad++, you can go change the charset that is being used to visualize the file, when you find the right charset you can import with it, or you can use Notepad++ to convert to another charset.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the encoding of your file is also UTF-8 (Notepad++ have this feature), or try to paste the content in the sql executor of phpmyadmin.

Comment: The file says utf-8 however, when I look at the sql file it has the problem as well. Should I be exporting the database as a different carset?

Comment: Did you checked if this chars are correct in the original database? The export should take care of the encoding.

Comment: The chars are correct in the original database. And when I export the database but don't save it as a file, The é remain ok. but if I export and check off to save it as a file the é become  Ã©

Comment: Seems a phpmyadmin issue then. Are you using the latest version? What's the encoding of your original database?